# I didn't get the bounty for a question I answered

Tags: support, feature-request, bounty

This question had a bounty: [Multiple partners in a family tree in d3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077696/multiple-partners-in-a-family-tree-in-d3-js/34078934#34078934)

Yesterday it was running on the grace period of 24 hours, and on expiry I didn't get any bounty reward.

Now the history of the above question is that the person had accepted my answer before starting the bounty on the question.

In the past week I got a few up votes, but it's strange that I didn't get the bounty. Can someone explain why?

Comment: There's a grace period of 24 hours after one week. Maybe wait until then?

Comment: @HamZa if it were in the grace period then also the bounty balloon of +300 is vanished..which is strange.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The bounty system is working as intended.  Bounties are only auto awarded to answers that are posted after the bounty was started.  From the [how bounties work page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts **an answer posted during the bounty period**, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration.

You mention that "the person had accepted my answer before starting the question on bounty."  This implies that your answer existed before the bounty.  Looking at the [post history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34077696/revisions), the bounty was started on December 8 and your answer was posted December 4.  Your answer is therefore ineligible for *automatic* awarding of the bounty and can only win the bounty if bounty owner take the explicit action of awarding it to you.

Comment: so you saying that the bounty owner has to award the points for that to be credited? but whats strange is that the bounty was given for "Reward existing answer"

Comment: @Cyril that's a disassociation between the bounty autoawarding system and the bounty reasons... I feel that it should be like that, since the one starting the bounty should also award it.

Comment: ok but i think the autorewarding system should be changed for this special case "Reward existing answer" as it clearly states that the answer is marked before the bounty.

Comment: @Cyril: that'd only work for a single answer. You can also reward an existing answer that is not the accepted answer.

Comment: @Thomas Well in that case if 10 people write any answer when the bounty is open under "Reward existing answer" they all get reward points... don't you think its buggy :)..only an accepted answer should get. In my case its just one answer.

Comment: @Cyril if you have a few more implementation detail (like how to handle those corner cases) you can propose a new [meta-tag:feature-request] for that change to the bounty system.

Comment: So shall i make a new question or shall i tag this one as feature request  can you please guide..@ryanyuyu

Comment: @Cyril Make a new question

Comment: @ryanyuyu what will happen in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45482663/get-audit-history-records-of-any-entity-record-as-per-crm-view

Comment: @ArunVinoth that new answer would qualify for the auto-awarded bounty because it is the highest voted answer posted while the bounty was active.  Since it is not accepted, it will receive only half the bounty amount.  Your answer was posted before the bounty started, so your post doesn't qualify for auto-awarding the bounty.

Comment: @ryanyuyu thank you so much, highly appreciated buddy..