# Reward existing answer bounty should be awarded to the answer present

Tags: feature-request

This ticket is in response to this Stack Overflow meta [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312522/i-didnt-get-the-bounty-for-a-question-i-answered/).

The story unfolds like this:

There was a question: [Multiple partners in a family tree in d3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077696/multiple-partners-in-a-family-tree-in-d3-js/34078934#34078934)

And I answered that question.

The person who created the question accepted my answer and started a bounty (of 300) under **"Reward existing answer"**

As per the bounty rules:

> If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts **an answer posted during the bounty period**, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration.

As the answer was selected before the bounty start so as per the rules above my answer was *ineligible for automatic awarding of the bounty.*

Now finally my concern is:

The autorewarding system should be changed for this special case "Reward existing answer" as it clearly states that the answer is marked before the bounty. Thus the system should automatically award the bounty points to the person who answers it (or whose answer is accepted) and not go to teh community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The autorewarding system should be changed for this special case "Reward existing answer" as it clearly states that the answer is marked before the bounty. Thus the system should automatically award the bounty points to the person who answers it(or whose answer is accepted) and not go to teh community.

No, "Reward existing answer" does **not** "clearly states that the answer is *marked* before the bounty" (emphasis added) it just clearly states that the bounty giver wants to reward an answer that already existed before the start of the bounty. I've seen quite a few instances where an OP who received multiple great answers decided to offer new bounties after the initial one to rewards those answers that were great but *not* accepted.

I've also seen cases where an bounty giver who put up a bounty to reward an existing answer got a new, much better answer (which sometimes showed that the accepted answer was in fact wrong) and changed their mind.

What's the lesson here? Don't rely on automatic rules to make the decisions that the bounty giver should make.

Comment: "Reward existing answer" clearly states that the answer is already present...or it should have have been "Reward Accepted Answer"...so is my point that this phrase is very misleading. And automatic rules behave strangely in this context...there should be a corrective measure in this front.